# Steps to connec to a odata provider using odata4j

Tags: odata4j

I have tried to consume a odata service , but iam getting an error while trying to get entities .

String serviceUrl = "http://services.odata.org/(S(mvnfyllpw41mbzvkme0o0zug))/ODataOData.svc/";

```
ODataConsumer consumer = ODataConsumers.create(serviceUrl);

// list category names
for (OEntity category : consumer.getEntities("Categories").execute()) {
  String categoryName = category.getProperty("Name", String.class).getValue();
  System.out.println("Category name: " + categoryName);
}
```

Comment: Share that error message please.